# Using Roxygen2 Template tags

Tags: r, roxygen, roxygen2

Could someone provide an example of how to properly use the Template Tags in `Roxygen2`. I have tried to do the most obvious thing (to me):

In my `packageName-package.R` file:

```
 #' [... other Roxygen blocks ...]
 #' 
 #' @templateVar testTemplateTag Testing one two
 NULL
```

Then in a file someFunction.R

```
 #' [... other Roxygen blocks ...]
 #'
 #' @template testTemplateTag
```

I get the error:

```
 Error : Can not find template testTemplateTag
```

I am trying to have one place to document commonly repeated definitions examples etc. When these things are nested within a set of functions I have been using `@inheritParms`. But some things, like definitions and and other descriptions, are used in several places. I've searched high and low for usage of `@template` and `@templateVar` and have not found anything.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at plyr. The templates live in `man-roxygen/`

Comment: Thanks Hadley. Thats a great example.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Perfect! Thanks @hadley. The GitHub version of plyr was the perfect example.

I will describe the process here for future overflowers.

### Using Templates with Roxygen2

1) You should create a folder to hold your templates: `man-roxygen/`

2) Each template is a `.R` file that lives in `man-roxygen/`

For example: `man-roxygen/someTemplate.R`

```
 #' ... [other roxygen2 tags and information] ...
 #'
 #' @param someParm A parameter that is used in several functions.
 #'
 #' ... [more roxygen2 tags and information] ...
```

3) Now in some other `roxygen2` block you can call **all** of that `roxygen2` code this way.

```
 #' ... [other roxygen2 tags and information] ...
 #'
 #' @template someTemplate
```

4) When you use the template you get everything in the `someTemplate.R` file.

Check out the [plyr package on GitHub](https://github.com/hadley/plyr) to see the clever way Hadley uses several template files stored in `man-roxygen\` that he can mix and match to create the documentation. Look at the following to get the idea:

Look for the use of `@template` in these files:

```
 R/aaply.r
 R/adply.r
```

Look at the templates here:

```
 man-roxygen/ply.r
 man-roxygen/a-.r
 man-roxygen/-a.r
 man-roxygen/-d.r
```

Comment: Any chance you have an example of how/when we can use the @templateVar tag?

Comment: This no longer works with roxygen2 (>= 4.0.1). You need to remove the `.R` in the template name. So, the following _will_ work ```@template someTemplate```.

Comment: Here is an example using @templateVar. The file [man-roxygen/graph_template.R](https://github.com/USCCANA/netdiffuseR/blob/master/man-roxygen/graph_template.R) defines a param graph that depends on `dyngraph`, the template is used in the file [R/stats.R](https://github.com/USCCANA/netdiffuseR/blob/6b1a7b81a530a882947679d198e65ba5eb3c4ff1/R/stats.R#L4-L7) and generates the file [dgr.R](https://github.com/USCCANA/netdiffuseR/blob/6b1a7b81a530a882947679d198e65ba5eb3c4ff1/man/dgr.Rd#L20-L28). HIH

Comment: @gvegayon That was very helpful! But what is the reason for having the double logical condition in e.g. "exists("self") && self"? For me, it works with just "exists("self")", but is there any feature I'm missing by having only this?

Comment: If -self- doesn't exists and I try to use it as logical condition, e.g. if (self), then it returns an error. So I use if (exits(.) && .) so that the second part is evaluated only if the first part is true.