# CRAN note when using roxygen2 template

Tags: r, cran, roxygen2

I'm using rogyxen2 template in my R package. As suggested, I added my template R files in a folder called "man-roxygen" in the package directory.

However, when I R CMD check I get the following note:

> Non-standard file/directory found at top level:
>     ‘man-roxygen’

Any way to fix this?

Cheers,
Philippe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add `man-roxygen` to the `.Rbuildignore` file.  See the **plyr** package and how it has done this [here](https://github.com/hadley/plyr).  And [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100129/using-roxygen2-template-tags/15143507#15143507) on SO might also be useful.