# Document Inherited slots from superclasses in roxygen2

Tags: r, roxygen2, roxygen

I'm tryin do document my S4 classes in roxygen2. I've a superclass FacebookGenericCollection with some slots I documented carefully and few subclasses that extend these slots.

Here's an example code for a subclass:

```
#' A collection of valid Facebook Pages.
#'
#' @family API Resources
#' @name FacebookPagesCollection-class
#' @exportClass FacebookPagesCollection
#'  
#' @export
setClass("FacebookPagesCollection",
         contains = "FacebookGenericCollection",
         slots = c(limit="numeric")
)
```

But when I build the Rd, only the "limit" slot is documented, while all those inherited from (and documented in) FacebookGenericCollection-class are not.

I'm searching for something similar to @inheritParams I use for functions.

I tried @import FacebookGenericCollection but without effects.

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Roxygen2 Template tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100129/using-roxygen2-template-tags)

Comment: This is very close to templating and could be solved this way